# HttpClient headers vs HttpContent headers

Tags: c#, .net, http-headers, httpclient, httpcontent

In c# why both HttpClient and HttpContent have headers. What is difference between them. When should I use client headers and when content headers ?

CODE EXAMPLE:

```
HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("Test header", "content");

HttpContent content = new StringContent("text", Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");
content.Headers.Add("TestHeader", "Header Content");

await client.PostAsync("url", content);
```

Comment: The client headers are the headers that should be sent for every request by default. The content headers are headers that should only be sent for this specific content/request.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

HttpClient supports several types of content. For example:

- System.Net.Http.ByteArrayContent
- System.Net.Http.Json.JsonContent
- System.Net.Http.MultipartContent
- System.Net.Http.ReadOnlyMemoryContent
- System.Net.Http.StreamContent

For a complete list of supported content, see [HttpContent](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.http.httpcontent?view=net-6.0).

HttpContent contains some more specific headers about the content, including the content type.

I think this list [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.http.headers.httpcontentheaders?view=net-6.0) can give you a pretty good understanding on what headers that are available. I do agree that having jus one set of headers would make things much easier.